# Unable to access resources from APKs on the SD Card.

Tags: android, resources, apk

I am using the following snippet to get the application name and icon of few of the APKs on my SD Card.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 0);
ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
Drawable appIcon = appInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
String appName = appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
```

I am able to access the package name but the **loadIcon** returns the default Android application icon for all the apks and the **loadLabel** returns the package name (Not the application label).

I also get the following warning messages in logcat:

```
Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020005 in package com.sample.radio
Failure retrieving text 0x7f050000 in package com.taskkiller.demo
```

I am running Android 2.2, any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have permission for reading/writing in the storage?

Comment: I tried including it now, but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 6):

You may need to add two lines before creating appIcon, AppName:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo    pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(APKFilePath, 0);

// NEW LINES
pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir = APKFilePath;
pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = APKFilePath; 

String   AppName = (String)pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);
Drawable appIcon=pm.getApplicationIcon(pi.applicationInfo);
```

Comment: You need to be specific about what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I would've thought it would be smart enough to know what APK I'm talking about after specifically using `getPackageArchiveInfo` with a specific path...but I guess not!